# Docker - Mysql container is restarting

Tags: mysql, docker

I am running a docker container locally on Ubuntu VM. The container is constantly getting restarted.

Logs while running pod

`Error response from daemon: Container 8345404f85a30f71d18e420eb064ef2104748f1f7b6d3a is restarting, wait until the container is running` 
Output of `docker ps`

```
8345404f85a3        mysql:5.7.23                                                                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 minutes ago       Restarting (1) 29 seconds ago
```

POD Error logs

```
2020-09-23T05:00:35.302191Z 0 [Warning] option 'max_binlog_size': unsigned value 10485760000 adjusted to 1073741824
2020-09-23T05:00:35.302252Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-09-23T05:00:35.303732Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open file '/var/log/mysql/error.log' for error logging: Is a directory
2020-09-23T05:00:35.307546Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Initializing database
2020-09-23T05:01:01.866333Z 0 [Warning] option 'max_binlog_size': unsigned value 10485760000 adjusted to 1073741824
2020-09-23T05:01:01.866398Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-09-23T05:01:01.872326Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open file '/var/log/mysql/error.log' for error logging: Is a directory
2020-09-23T05:01:01.872464Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that the error cannot open file /var/log/mysql/error.log is the primary problem. Yo should check if that location exists, and the permissions on it are correct. See this for a similar case: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004039393-Unable-to-start-mysql-var-log-mysql-error-log-Permission-denied. Maybe the image expects that there is a volume mounted for logging. Is there something about that in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone gets an error on MySQL in Docker / Lando with the following, and they are using a `Dockerfile`.

`database_1 | 2023-03-30T11:05:57.081370Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open file '/opt/bitnami/mysql/logs/mysqld.log' for error logging: Permission denied`

Then solution could be to ensure that `USER 1001` is set as the last `USER` command in the `Dockerfile`. I encounted this when setting `USER root` to run `apt-get update` and friends.